Imagick creating PDF even though setImageFormat is set to JPEG
I have an odd issue that I cannot get to the bottom of. I'm using Imagick to generate JPG thumbnails of PDFs that are uploaded to a custom admin tool. However, Imagick is creating PDF files even though setImageFormat is set to JPEG and to add to the confusion this only happens when a PDF file has a single page. If it's a multipage PDF, the jpg thumbnails are created.
public function generateCopies() {
    if (empty($this->copyPathFormats)) {
        return True;
    }

    if (! is_array($this->copyPathFormats)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Asset::copyPathFormat must be an array. '.gettype($this->copyPathFormats).' provided.');
    }

    foreach ($this->copyPathFormats as $key => $copyPathFormat) {
        if ($key === 'finder') {
            continue;
        }

        $path = $this->basePath.$this->pathParamSubstitution($copyPathFormat, $this->pathParam);
        if (! (is_dir($path) || mkdir($path, 0777, True))) {
            throw new \RuntimeException($path.' could not be found or created.');
        }

        $img = new \Imagick($this->path.$this->name);
        $img->setImageCompressionQuality( 89 );
        
        $copyName = $this->name;
        $format = $img->getImageFormat();

        if ($format === 'PDF') {
            $img = new \Imagick();
            $img->setResolution(150,150);
            $img->readImage($this->path.$this->name.'[0]');
            $img->setImageCompressionQuality( 70 );
            $img = $img->flattenImages(); 
            $img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
            $filename  = pathinfo($this->name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $copyName = $filename.'.jpg';
        }

        $geometry = $img->getImageGeometry();
        $width  = $geometry['width'] >= $geometry['height'] ? $this->copySizeConstraints[$key] : 0;
        $height = $geometry['height'] > $geometry['width'] ? $this->copySizeConstraints[$key] : 0;

        if ($img->scaleImage($width,$height,False) !== True) {
            \RuntimeException('Cannot resize the image.');
        }

        if ($img->writeImage($path.$copyName) !== True) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot write the resized copy to '.$path.$this->name);
        }
        $img->destroy();
    }

    return True;
}


https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageformat.php#112572

Unfortunately the above didn't help. And to clarify, my above function does work on multi-page PDFs. A jpg thumbnail of the first page is created. It's only when running the above function on a single page PDF, a thumbnail is created but the extension/format is PDF.

thanks for the feedback, very insightful. IMHO it's very helpful if you sort in those details into your question by editing it. What you describe is not that far off with the reference as the distinction is between those two things in Imagick and it is often not clear whether the image is an image or the image is an object, what is affected and how. Whether or not a file has one or more images depends on the file and then there are  these misunderstandings, misconceptions and misinterpretations what when how and where applies when throwing methods onto it.

My question specifically states the details. PDF to JPG thumbnails. If it's a single page PDF, Imagick creates a PDF even when the format that is set is JPG. If it's a multipage PDF, then Imagick creates JPG.

As you mentioned yourself in the comment - no offence - there is a difference between PDF and PDF, and in the question more specifically between Imagick Image Converversion to JPEG and Imagick Image Conversion to JPEG specifically. Work with the differences, especially when they are close. This is the interesting part.

Solved the problem here. Even though the PDFs are indeed PDFs, they were exported from Adobe Illustrator. Imagemagick therefore was interpreting these as AI files. Once I updated my if statement to also include AI, things started working as expected.
$img = new \Imagick($this->path.$this->name);
        $copyName = $this->name;
        $format = $img->getImageFormat();
        

        if ($format === 'PDF' or $format === 'AI') {
                            
            $img = new \Imagick();
            
            
            $img->setResolution(150,150);
            $img->setColorspace(1);
            $img->readImage($this->path.$this->name.'[0]');
            
            
            $img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
            $img->setFormat('jpeg');
            $img->setImageCompressionQuality( 70 );
            $img = $img->flattenImages(); 
            
            $filename  = pathinfo($this->name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $copyName = $filename.'.jpg';
        }

